# Set builder to set roster notation (Sets)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation

$S=\{n ∈ \mathbb{Z} \mid n=(−2)^k, k ∈ \mathbb{Z}\}$

If I were to take the above set builder notation set to set roster notation, would the new set have one element -2<sup>k</sup> or would it be 2 elements -2<sup>k</sup> and -2<sup>-k</sup> because I don't know what the integer k is.

For the set below, is this an empty set? Or because there's an or would I write this as a set of 2 sets?

$V ={\{s ∈ \mathbb{Z} \mid s>3 \vee    s<4\}}$

*EDIT : If someone could explain what is and isn't allowed in set roster notation that'd be great! I'm quite new to this and my textbook doesn't say whether or not we can use R or Z or inequalities in parentheses in set roster notation.

Comment: "set roster" is the list of elements of the set : "the set of *odd* integers less than $10$" = $\{ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 \}$.

Comment: For $V$ : yes, we can rewrite it as the union of two sets : $V_1 = \{ s \in \mathbb Z \mid s > 3 \}$ and $V_2 = \{ s \in \mathbb Z \mid s < 4 \}$.